# Using FTCSPI.dll functions from FTD2XX.DLL, Using FT2232H device

Tags: c#, ftdi

I have a FT2232H device, I need to use the SPI methods which are at the ***FTCSPI.dll*** programming guide
For example

```
SPI_OpenHiSpeedDevice(LPSTR lpDeviceName, DWORD dwLocationID, LPSTR
lpChannel, FTC_HANDLE *pftHandle)
```

I already use other FTDI devices with the manufacture`s c# wrapper class ***FTD2XX_NET*** ([Taken from here](https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/code-examples/csharp-examples/)) and it works fine

But there are no calls to SPI method there, I also did not found these method at the ***FTD2XX.DLL*** documentation.
But at the [Programmers Guide For High Speed Ftcspi Dll](http://www.datasheetdir.com/Programmers-Guide-For-High-Speed-Ftcspi-Dll+Application-Notes)
it says:

> The FTCSPI DLL has been created to allow application developers to use the FT2232D FT2232H and
> FT4232H devices to create a USB to Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) protocol Interface without any
> knowledge of the MPSSE command set. **All of the functions in FTCSPI.DLL CAN be replicated using calls to
> FTD2XX.DLL and sending the appropriate commands to the MPSSE.**

How can I call the method specified at the start of the question using FTD2XX.DLL

Answer (score 0):

The FTD2XX.DLL allows you to send commands to the MPSSE engine. The dedicated SPI and I2C mode version are basically "built" ontop of the MPSSE/FTD2XX.DLL - they generate the appropriate MPSSE command sequences from the SPI/I2C parameters, which are then sent to the engine.

So you can "copy" this sequences generation into your code and skip the use of FTCSPI completely. Question is: is there any reason to not use the FTCSPI? One valid reason is that one wants to avoid the hardcoded INFRA_SLEEP ( https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442388/remove-time-gaps-before-chip-select-disabled-on-ftdi ).